# how to capture ok button pressed from JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to capture the ok button event when the "OK" button is pressed in on a JOptionPane. I then want to display a jframe. I've found numerous tutorials and videos on capturing all sorts of events except for the JOptionPane. The Java docs are not much help for a newbie. Hoping someone can help. I have the following.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Press OK to get a frame");
```

How do I implement the listener to capture the OK pressed event.

```
private class Listener implements ActionListener {

    public void
      actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it when the program continues? Because when the user clicks ok then the dialog disposes and the your code just moves on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to capture it -- code flow will return immediately post the `JOptionPane` display line. If you want to know if OK vs cancel vs delete the window was pressed, then use a different `JOptionPane` -- use the `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)`, and capture the result returned from this method call.

```
    String text = "Press OK to get a frame";
    String title = "Show Frame";
    int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, text, title, optionType);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with the `showMessageDialog` method. You have to use the `showConfirmDialog` method instead. This will return you a value on which you can determine the button that was pressed:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Press OK to get a frame");

if (result  == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
     // Yes button was pressed
} else if (result  == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
     // No button was pressed
}
```

To get the OK Button you need to use `OK_CANCEL_OPTION`:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Press OK to get a frame",
                                     "Title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

if (result  == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
     // OK button was pressd
} else if (result  == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
     // Cancel button was pressed
}
```